# Using middleware route filer in Entrust for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, middleware, entrust

I have used [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust#short-syntax-route-filter) for laravel, everything works fine until I used the middleware route filter.

Like I said everything works fine apart from the middlware filter. I have added the routemiddleware array to kernel.  So this is basically  what the filter looks like, same thing that is found in the docs:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['role:admin']], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@welcome');
    Route::get('/manage', ['middleware' => ['permission:manage-admins'], 'uses' => 'AdminController@manageAdmins']);
});
```

But I've got this error:

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 779: Class role:admin does
>   not exist

Comment: Did you add the lines in Kernel?

Answer (score 0):

after you finish installation, you need run `composer dump-autoload` ,and make sure you follow every step of the doc

Comment: done all that, including clearing cache, but same result.